# Не выполняются потоки

Tags: c, pthread

В программе два потока. Один выводит 5 строк, второй - массив чисел. Программа компилируется, но нет никакого результата выполения, ничего не выводится. Скажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема, что не так делаю?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void * func1(void * args)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        printf("Thread %d\n", i);
        sleep(2);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void * func2(void * args)
{
    int arr[10];
    int i = 0;

    for (i; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = 0 +rand() % (10 + 0 +1);
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    int res1, res2;

    res1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &func1, NULL);
    if (res1 != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error1\n");
        return 1;
    }

    res2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &func2, NULL);
    if (res2 != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error2\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего программа завершается до того, как отработают потоки. Можно перед `return 0` поставить вызов [sleep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sleep.html), [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html) или [pthread_exit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_exit.html).